# How do I create a FlatButton with an Image that opens a URL in a WebView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to create a `FlatButton` with an image that opens a specific URL within a `WebView` in Flutter.

How could I achieve that?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // Flat Image Button with Inkwell Ripple and 'URL'. //

           Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              child: FlatButton(
                splashColor: Colors.grey[300],
                highlightColor: Colors.white,
                color: Colors.white,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                onPressed: (){
                  // Navigator.pop(context); // Closes the Drawer
                  Navigator.push(context, 
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WebViewContainer('URL Goes Here'),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/logo-1.png" //.png with transparent background to insure Successful Ink Ripple effect.
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Material widget to create a image which acts as button or you can use gesture detector widget with image as child and onTap method navigate to new page/screen and in that page/screen you can use [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) to load a desired url.
By following the example from above package you can meet your requirements.

```
    GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {//here navigate to new page and in scaffold use webview
}
        child: Image.asset('path/the_image.png')
    )
```

And for webview

```
WebView(
 initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
 javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
  );
```

Comment: Thank you Kindly for your Swift response, I shall give it a Try.